# Are there art supplies that create a new color by mixing through a chemical reaction?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, safety, color

When two elements or compounds react together, they form new compounds, which more often than not assume new colors. If the two elements or compounds don't react, they form uniform or non-uniform mixtures, in which case the new color which results from the mixing is the result of the direct combination of the light of emitted by the original elements or compounds. These colors affect the red, green, and blue light receptors inside human eyes, producing a perceptual sensation of color.

I want to know, are there any safe colored substances or color media, which can be used together by an artist, notably a typical artist working from home on paper, cardboard, or canvas materials, and which when mixed together to form a new color, as artists do, actually generates a color resulting from a chemical reaction rather than substance mixing, and, **above all, the chemical reaction is safe in terms of not causing damage to the eyes or skin.**

Comment: Can you please reword the first paragraph? Admittedly, I might not have fully understood what you asked. Anyway: I am not aware of a system where different dyes are reacted with each other. This doesn't mean that there isn't any ;-) Chemical reactions to play a role when reactive dyes are (irreversibly) anchored to a fibre or when the dye is first applied in its reduced form and then reacted (with oxygen) to yield the final colour. This is pretty much what happens during vat dying with indigo or purple.

Comment: Interesting answer @KlausWarzecha. What about the colors wood, brick, plastic, metal dyes for houses, furniture and cars, as well aspens, pencils, pastels, oil paint, and eyeliner, and lipstick, nail polish are made of. Are there any chemical reactions taking place there, before these dyes are used, or are those just mixtures as well, and if so, then of what?

Comment: As for dyes, as chemical compounds are scarce, both from a sustainability point of view, but abstractly, in terms of number of combinatorial combinations, I would guess that dyes must result from mixing different combinations of substances, otherwise we could not have that many colors. I wonder where these substances are taken from.

Comment: What about hair dyes. Do they actually just blend, or do they react upon entering the hair. What are they made of, and what makes them safe and skin friendly versus harmful to both the skin and the environment?

Comment: Ceramic glazes often change colors during firing - this is typically just an oxidation reaction.

Comment: Unlikely, because the components of this reaction would likely be susceptible to reactions with air or water. Definitely it must be a special combination, which is hardly usable as paint individually. Real paint also is usually not coloured with dye, but pigments, i.e. inorganic particles.  You can sure make something that works, but it probably won't be harmless.